# How to use composite primary key for deletion

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-delete, composite-primary-key

I'm new to the database and my question is how can I use composite primary key for deletion. here is my table structure,

```
CREATE TABLE DevProj (
    DeveloperID int NOT NULL,
    ProjectID int NOT NULL,
    WorkDate Datetime,
    WorkingHours int,
    Overtime int,
    Descriptions varchar(255),
    Primary key(DeveloperID,ProjectID,WorkDate) 
);

insert into DevProj (DeveloperID,ProjectID,WorkDate,WorkingHours,Overtime,Descriptions) values
(1,2,'2018-1-1',10,5,'done all'),
(1,2,'2018-1-2',10,5,'done C++'),
(1,3,'2018-1-1',10,5,'done C#'),
(2,2,'2018-1-3',10,5,'done JAVA'),
(3,3,'2018-1-4',10,5,'done SQL');
```

suppose I need to delete `(1,2,'2018-1-1',10,5,'done all')` this record, how can I do that, there is composite priamry key and no individual column as a primary key to delete like this, Ex: `Delete from devProj where id = 1` .So then, how can I write query for delete record, I faced this problem when the updation also.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, to delete several records:

```
DELETE FROM DevProj 
WHERE (DeveloperID, ProjectID, WorkDate) IN ((1,2,'2018-1-1'), ((1,2,'2018-1-2'))
```

**Additional performance considerations**

But please note that if you have a MySQL version lower than 5.7.11, this will not take advantage of the index optimization (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html#row-constructor-range-optimization). In such case, you should use AND/OR operators:

```
DELETE FROM DevProj 
WHERE (DeveloperID = 1 AND ProjectID = 2 AND WorkDate = '2018-1-1') 
OR (DeveloperID = 1 AND ProjectID = 2 AND WorkDate = '2018-1-2')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a record based on the composite primary key, you could use MySQL's shorthand:

```
DELETE
FROM DevProj
WHERE (DeveloperID, ProjectID, WorkDate) = (1, 2, '2018-01-01');
```

Or you could use the longer version:

```
DELETE
FROM DevProj
WHERE
    DeveloperID = 1 AND
    ProjectID = 2 AND
    WorkDate) = '2018-01-01';
```

Comment: Thank you sir, can I use another key with composite primary key, I mean, like this.    `DevProjID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Primary key(DevProjID)` Is this good thing or bad thing? If I use like that I can write a query for delete. `Delete from devProj where DevProjID= 1`

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  I don't see any column called `DevProjID` in your table.

Comment: No no, I mean if I add additional column for table, called `DevProjID`.

`CREATE TABLE DevProj (
 DevProjID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DeveloperID int NOT NULL,
    ProjectID int NOT NULL,
 WorkDate Datetime,
 WorkingHours int,
 Overtime int,
 Descriptions varchar(255),
 Primary key(DevProjID),
 Primary key(DeveloperID,ProjectID,WorkDate) 
);`

Comment: I think a MySQL table can only have a single primary key.  Just try that syntax and you will see it fail.

Comment: yes. I cant do it, this error displaying. **1068. Multiple primary key defined** I think is I use **DevProjID**  not as a primary. I can use this query `Delete from devProj where DevProjID= 1` because its easy than a write a query like `DELETE
FROM DevProj
WHERE (DeveloperID, ProjectID, WorkDate) = (1, 2, '2018-01-01');`  Is that wrong thing?

Comment: I can't comment further because I don't know where you're coming from.